# Pass argument to controller methods

Tags: controller

Is it possible to pass arguments to controller action methods, like

`public function someAction($myArgument) { ... }`

Or is using `JInput` the only way?

**Edit**: Using a URL like `option=com_mycomponent&task=mycontroller.someaction&myargument=asd`

Comment: Where are you calling it, from an URL, or another function?

Comment: @PieroMarsilio From a URL

Comment: well then I think only using JInput or a session variable previously stored. Maybe if you explain some more what do you want to achieve maybe we can help you out.

Comment: Just looking for less idiosyncratic ways to do things than classic Joomla. ^^

Comment: You can override the execute method and add something like `callBindedFunction` at https://github.com/joomplace/JooYii/blob/master/Helper.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to pass arguments into methods.  Specifically, this has to do with how `JControllerLegacy::execute()` routes the request.  So you're left with using the request or session to fetch your needed data.